# How to save on connectivity between VM to Agent and continues in long pipeline step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I runs a Jenkins which have some steps (prepare VMs before tests, check connectivity between Agents to VMs and running the tests) when the last step took approximately 10 hours  and sometimes the connection betwenn the agent to the VM is down.
My question is if there any way to save on connectivity betwenn the VM to the agent and to could be recover from failers (reconnect the agent to VM and continue the tests when it stops)

**more information:**
I ran a java application with **mvn clean install**

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of solutions to recover a pipeline on slave disconnection.

However regarding slave re-connection I would use a simple cron like the following:

https://github.com/fredericrous/JenkinsDevEnv/blob/master/jenkins-slave-init#L43